# How to loop through a json key that value is an array

Tags: json, bash

I am somewhat new to bash. My Objective is to loop through the JSON and capture the user input and export it to environment variable.

This is the structure of the json. Any help will be appreciated!

```
{
  "items": [{
      "Gitlab": [
        "GITLAB_URL",
        "GITLAB_TOKEN",
        "GITLAB_CHANNEL",
        "GITLAB_SHOW_COMMITS_LIST",
        "GITLAB_SHOW_MERGE_DESCRIPTION",
        "GITLAB_DEBUG",
        "GITLAB_BRANCHES"
      ]
    },
    {
      "PagerDuty": [
        "PAGERV2_API_KEY",
        "PAGERV2_SCHEDULE_ID",
        "PAGERV2_SERVICES",
        "PAGERV2_DEFAULT_RESOLVER",
        "PAGERV2_ENDPOINT",
        "PAGERV2_ANNOUNCE_ROOM",
        "PAGERV2_NEED_GROUP_AUTH",
        "PAGERV2_LOG_PATH"
      ]
    },
    {
      "SLack": [
        "SLACK_TOKEN"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I have so far

```
 jq '.items[] | select( .Gitlab| startswith("first-block-"))' < configurations.json

for i in ${items[@]}
do
echo "Enter your " $i
read  input
if [[ ! -z "$input" ]]; then
  export $i=$input
fi
done
```

Comment: It would be easier for a `bash` user if you posted the output of the `jq` command, what you want to process in plain `bash`

Comment: I don't see how your `jq` command relates to your `bash` code at all. The question is unclear

Comment: There's no `first-block-` anywhere in the JSON.

Comment: Hi guys, this is the error message I am getting.
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.items[] | select( .Gitlab))                           
jq: 1 compile error